# HTTPRequest performance VBScript vs. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, performance, vbscript

I have an application that uses a VBScript file within operation to make HTTP requests and I would like to preferably move this to a VB.NET solution entirely.

I know there are some differences in the VBScript HTTP requests and the VB.NET ones, but what I really want to know is which one will be faster? After some tests with VB.NET I'm not so sure it will be as fast as my VBScript solution. Does anyone have experience with this and is there even a noticeable change in performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect VB.Net to be faster, because however fast the actual httprequest calls are, using vbscript means your app will first need to spin up a separate process.

That said, what will *far and away drive the performance* here is the actual web download. We're talking several dozen to hundreds of milliseconds for the web server to prepare and transmit it's response vs *at most* a few 10s of milliseconds difference for vbscript vs vb.net, even when considering the time to start a new process.

Comment: Marked as answer. I ended up using the VB.NET WebClient class for my requests and was quick and painless to convert it. It is MUCH easier to manage the code now that it's all in the same language instead of relying on VBScript for the requests.